# Change loading image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loading

I want to have my loading image be different each time i start the app. Is there a way to change this to something else once the app's started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not technically, no. The startup images are located inside the application bundle - as part of iOS's sandboxing, applications can't change or modify files inside that bundle (so your Info.plist and your background images).

It would be possible to have your startup image be black, and then swap it out for another splash screen that you hold for a few seconds as soon as your `applicationDidFinishLoading` method is called - but remember this will degrade the user experience, since you'll be delaying the time it takes to get into the app.